# Divisibility of big numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose we have a number $N$ with $x$ digits and we want to determine whether $N$ is divisible by a number $M$ with $y$ digits such that $x > y$.

How do I go about this? I tried to use the first $y$ digits of $N$ and divide them by $M$ but I'm not sure this is true for all $N$ and $M$. Is there a general rule of thumb for problems like this?

Comment: You may be interested by [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule).

Comment: The general rule is to test whether or not the value of $N/M$ is integer.

Comment: Factoring is one of the hardest task and requires exponential time. On the difficulty of this task is based public key criptography, where large primes (500 digit primes I mean) are multiplied and factoring requires more than the age of universe even with the most powerful supercomputer. Urban legends tells the story of quantum computers which could theoretically factor these numbers in minutes. Google invested several million $ and they get the quite amazing result to factor 143....

Comment: Building off @Raffaele, I'd look at brute force algorithms designed for breaking keys. That's going to be your best bet although I suspect that you asked this question with that in mind.

Comment: For a given $M$ you can just do long division.  It is not very time consuming.  The problem in factoring is that there are so many possible $M$s, not that checking an individual one is slow.

Comment: You might be interested in [large-integer methods for the division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large-integer_methods).

Comment: @Trey Your question doesn't ask to find $M$, only to determine whether such an $M$ exists.  To answer that yes/no question, assuming that $y$ is not prescribed, is easily reduced to testing for primality, which can be done in time polynomial in $x$.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Is $M$ given? If not, is $y$ given?

Comment: To build upon @RossMillikan ‘s answer (should’ve been the answer, anyway!): use long division (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), then check if the remainder is zero.

Comment: @Raffaele - Just a quick technicality - The Quadratic Sieve and Number Field Sieve, while they haven't been analyzed rigorously, are heuristically subexponential factoring algorithms (though they are beyond polynomial time), and it has actually not been proven that factoring cannot be done in polynomial time. Dixon's algorithm, which is usually slower than the proceeding two, has been analyzed rigorously as subexponential. So I would be hesitant to assert that factoring "requires" exponential time, only that our best known algorithms aren't any better than subexponential at best.

Comment: @Christian Thank you! I am not a specialist. My comment was semi-serious and a bit polemical about  *vaporware* like *quantum computers*... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below is good for **small values** $y$. Say, for $y\le 12$. 

 And it is closely related to divisibility rules.

Explained via example:

 let

$$N = 1529773658514887677106240187604962388655195023566;$$
$$M=14159.$$

Since $y=5$, we group digits of the number $N$ by $5$:
$$N = \color{gray}{0}1529\;\;77365\;\;85148\;\;87677\;\;10624\;\;01876\;\;04962\;\;38865\;\;51950\;\;23566;\tag{1}$$
and rewrite $N$ as
$$N = a_9\cdot 100000^9 + a_8 \cdot 100000^8 + \cdots + a_1 \cdot 100000 + a_0,\tag{2}$$
where $0\le a_j < 100000$.

We'll find number $v$ ($0\le v < 100000$), for which 
$$N \equiv v (\bmod M).\tag{3}$$
If $v=0$, then $N$ is divisible by $M$.

So, we find remainders of $10000$, $10000^2$, $\ldots$, $10000^9$ first:
\begin{array}{rcr}
100000 &\equiv &\color{darkred}{887} (\bmod 14159),\\
  100000^2\equiv 887\cdot 887=786769 &\equiv &\color{darkred}{8024} (\bmod 14159),\\
  100000^3\equiv 887\cdot 8024=7117288 & \equiv &\color{darkred}{9470} (\bmod 14159),\\
   & \cdots &  \\
  100000^8 &\equiv &\color{darkred}{11965} (\bmod 14159),\\
  100000^9 &\equiv &\color{darkred}{7864} (\bmod 14159).
\end{array}

Therefore
\begin{array}{r}N \equiv 01529\cdot \color{darkred}{7864} \\
+ 77365 \cdot \color{darkred}{11965} \\ 
+ \cdots \quad\\
+ 04962 \cdot \color{darkred}{9470} \\
+ 38865 \cdot \color{darkred}{8024} \\
+ 51950 \cdot \color{darkred}{887} \\
+ 23566 \cdot \color{darkred}{1} \\
\equiv 0 (\bmod 14159).
\end{array}
So, $N$ is divisible by $M$.

---

Relation to divisibility rules:

 if $M=3$, then $y=1$, and we note that 
$$10\equiv 1 (\bmod 3);\\
10^2\equiv 1 (\bmod 3);\\
10^3\equiv 1 (\bmod 3);\\
\cdots$$
and for $$N=a_j\cdot 10^j + a_{j-1}\cdot 10^{j-1}+\cdots + a_1\cdot 10 + a_0$$
 we have 
$$N\equiv a_j + a_{j-1}+\cdots + a_1 + a_0 (\bmod 3)$$
(iif $N$ is divisible by $3$ then sum of its digits is divisible by $3$).

Answer (score 1):

You ask two or three questions:

1. Suppose we have a number N with x digits ...

If x = 1 then it's easy enough, I suppose.

If x > 1 googolplex then if someone could answer your question, if humanity from now on would develop machines specifically designed to solve this problem, then you'd not be alive to receive the answer.

Pulling people off of the task of answering the problem to devote themselves to ensuring your offspring continued, so they could accept the answer on your behalf, would only increase the time it took to solve the problem; and give your offspring the answer to a single pair of numbers (assuming x was enormous, or that you wanted more than one pair of numbers solved for).

2. How do I go about this?

In a comment to your question @Harry49 gives this link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule - I have no problem with that answer, it is one correct method albeit not a quick method.

3. Is there a general rule of thumb for problems like this?

Rule of thumb:

- What if the question was: "How do I go about counting all the atoms in the universe?" (unlike your question, that question has a clearly defined bound and it's a single question with one number produced as the answer).
- What if the agreed upon answer was: "You make a huge jar and count how many atoms it is made of, then you take each atom in the universe and place it in the jar; counting each as you go.".

---

So back we go to the "divisability rules" given in #2, and your question: "How do I go about this?".

The "answer" is either "Follow the divisibility rule", **or** the answer is "You, or we, do not (go about doing that)".

Even if a huge shortcut could be developed there's a huge number of numbers and providing the answer to a very large number would take a very long time, a prohibitively long time.

If X was trivial you could probably just look at it and know, much as some people know a large multiplication table, you could know a large division table - knowing that doesn't answer you question any better than using divisibility rules (which is unhelpful) or deriving an enormous shortcut (which would take an enormous amount of time, as would writing out the answer if we knew it).

Your problem is unbounded and thus unsolvable, giving the answer for **one** large X would take forever as would developing the fastest shortcut.

It's somewhat like asking "How do I calculate the last digit of π?". We can give you the best algorithm and computer but the doing is another matter. If your current position could be saved and transferred to a faster computer, or a better algorithm, you'd still not have a answer anytime soon (or late). How would you do it?, you would not.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to divide M into N and check for remainder as propsed by [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455480/divisibility-of-big-numbers#comment5248722_2455480) in the comments section. You can do it with long division, where you have I believe $O(log(N/M)) = O(x-y)$ multiplications, subtractions and divisions (which we can disregard, since the reulst from those division is always exactly one digit, thus we can assume it is constant operation. The same thing aplies to multiplication since we're multiplicating M by a single digit). Most difficult of these is actually the subtraction which will take $O(x)$. Total is bound by $O(x^2)$. Maybe better explanation of this part can be found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486152/how-is-schoolbook-long-division-an-on2-algorithm).

Since I assume you are interested in big x and y and you want to be a little faster, you can do the division with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large-integer_methods), which transforms the problem of set of multiplications, for which you can use FFT getting a complexity of $O(x*log(x)*log(log(x)))$.

There are of course the special cases of M being the $n$-th power of 2 where you need to check divisibility of only the first $n$ digits of N or other divisibility rules as shown earlier here but for the general case you have to do the division somehow and check for the remainder.